# Electron phonon coupling field integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, phonons

I am stuck on the problem "electron-phonon coupling" part a in Altland and Simons page 187. There is a [related question on PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576596/electron-phonon-coupling-within-field-integral-formalism), but that concerns part b.

Borrowing from the notation in the link above:

We want to formulate the coherent state action of the electron-phonon system. The action is given by
$$
S[\bar{\phi},\phi,\bar{\psi},\psi] = S_{ph}[\bar{\phi},\phi] + S_{el}[\bar{\psi},\psi] + S_{el-ph}[\bar{\phi},\phi,\bar{\psi},\psi],
$$
where $S_{el}$ is the electronic non interacting action, which we don't need here, $S_{ph}$ is the free phonons action, and $S_{el-ph}$ is the action of the interaction:
$$
S_{ph} \; [\bar{\phi},\phi] = \sum_{q,j} \bar{\phi}_{qj}( - i\omega_n + \omega_q ) \phi_{qj}
$$
$$
S_{el-ph} \; \; [\bar{\phi},\phi,\bar{\psi},\psi] = \gamma \sum_{qj} \frac{i \vec{q}\cdot \vec{e}_j}{\sqrt{2m\omega_q}} \sum_{k,\sigma} \bar{\psi}_{k+q,\sigma} \psi_{k\sigma} (\phi_{qj} + \bar{\phi}_{-qj}).
$$
Here $\omega_q$ is the phonon dispersion relation, supposed to be dependent on $q$ only and such that $\omega_{-q}=\omega_q$, $j$ labels the phononic branches, $\sigma$ labels the electronic spin, $i\omega_n$ are Matsubara bosonic frequencies, $m$ and $\gamma$ are constants.

We are supposed to get the formula for $S_{el-ph} \; \; [\bar{\phi},\phi,\bar{\psi},\psi]$ from
$$
H_{el-ph} \, = \gamma \sum_{k, q, j} \, \frac{i q_j}{(2 m \omega_q)^{1/2}} \; n_q \; (a_{q, j} + a^\dagger_{-q, j}).
$$
I was able to get the formula for $S_{ph}\; [\bar{\phi},\phi]$, as the Hamiltonian mirrors the Hamiltonian given in equation (4.26) on page 167. I'm stuck getting the formula for $S_{el-ph} \; \; [\bar{\phi},\phi,\bar{\psi},\psi]$ because

i. it seems we have both the Grassman field $\psi$ and the complex field $\phi$, and as opposed to the Hamiltonian discussed previously on page 167, we now have creation/annihilation operators ($a_{q, j} + a^\dagger_{-q, j}$,) appearing by themselves and not in pairs.

ii. I would have expected to have a term like $- i\omega_n$, like there is in $S_{ph} \; [\bar{\phi},\phi]$ and equation 4.27 on page 167, but it is not present in  the desired expression for $S_{el-ph} \; \; [\bar{\phi},\phi,\bar{\psi},\psi]$.

Comment: (i) as long as your operators are normal-ordered, you can follow the process of constructing the field path integral and replace bosonic operators by complex numbers and fermionic ones by Grassmann numbers. (ii) the -I\omega_n comes from d_\tau, which comes from the normalisation of the coherent states. you WILL have -iomega_n in the phonon part of the action

Comment: If you don't mind, could you elaborate a bit?  In particular, since there is both $\psi$ and $\phi$, I am thinking about taking a tensor product of states $\psi$ and $\phi$, but I don't see tensor products of Grassman fields and complex fields discussed anywhere in the chapter. The book has solutions immediately following the problem, but they write the action down in one step so it's a little hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a typo in the book: in the first equation on page 188, you shouldn't have the summation over $\mathbf{k}$, but whatever.

Let's start with the Hamiltonian:
$$
H = H_e + H_p + H_{ep} = H_e + \sum_{\mathbf{q}} \omega_{\mathbf{q}}a_{\mathbf{q}}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{q}} + \sum_\mathbf{q}\Gamma_\mathbf{q}\hat{n}_\mathbf{q}(a_\mathbf{q}+a^\dagger_{-\mathbf{q}})\,.
$$

To make the notation shorter, I suppressed the $j$ index and lumped the entire coupling term into $\Gamma_\mathbf{q}$.

We assume that $H_e$ is normal-ordered and write out the remaining part explicitly to show the fermionic operators:

$$
H = H_e + \sum_{\mathbf{q}} \omega_{\mathbf{q}}a_{\mathbf{q}}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{q}} + \sum_{\mathbf{qk}}\Gamma_\mathbf{q}c_{\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{k}}^\dagger c_\mathbf{k}(a_\mathbf{q}+a^\dagger_{-\mathbf{q}})\,.
$$

Using the fact that a product of two fermionic operators behaves like a bosonic one, we write

$$
H = H_e + \sum_{\mathbf{q}} \omega_{\mathbf{q}}a_{\mathbf{q}}^\dagger a_{\mathbf{q}} 
+ \sum_{\mathbf{qk}}\Gamma_\mathbf{q}c_{\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{k}}^\dagger c_\mathbf{k}a_\mathbf{q}
+ \sum_{\mathbf{qk}}\Gamma_\mathbf{q}a^\dagger_{-\mathbf{q}} c_{\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{k}}^\dagger c_\mathbf{k}\,,
$$
which is now normal-ordered.

Next, we do the usual dance:

$$
\sum_n\langle n|e^{-\beta H}|n\rangle = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_n\langle n|e^{-\delta H}e^{-\delta H}\dots e^{-\delta H}|n\rangle\,,
$$
where $\delta = \beta / N$.

Now, between each pair of $e^{-\delta H}$ terms, we insert a coherent resolvent sums for the two operator species. Let's focus on one of the $e^{-\delta H}$ terms:

$$
1 \, e^{-\delta H} \,1
\approx
1\left[1-\delta H\right]1 
\\
= \int d(\phi_l,\bar\phi_l)d(\bar\psi_l,\psi_l)
e^{-\sum_{\; \mathbf{q}} \, \bar\phi_{\; l,\mathbf{q} \;} \, \phi_{\; l,\mathbf{q} \; }}
\; e^{-\sum_\mathbf{q} \, \bar\psi_{\; l,\mathbf{q \; }\; } \, \psi_{\; 
 l,\mathbf{q} \; }}\; |\phi_l\rangle\otimes|\psi_l\rangle
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
\\
\left[1-\delta H\right]
\\
\int d(\phi_{l+1 \; },\bar\phi_{l+1 \; })d(\bar\psi_{l+1 \; },\psi_{l+1 \; })
\; e^{-\sum_\mathbf{\; q} \, \bar\phi_{\, l+1,\mathbf{q \; }} \; \;  \phi_{\, l+1,\mathbf{q \; }}}
\, \; \; e^{-\sum_\mathbf{\; q \; } \, \bar\psi_{\; 
 l+1,\mathbf{q} \; } \; \; \psi_{ \; 
 l+1,\mathbf{q \; }}}\; \; |\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
\langle\phi_{l+1}|\otimes\langle\psi_{l+1}|
\\
= \int d(\dots)
e^{-\sum_\mathbf{\; q \; } \; \bar\phi_{\; l,\mathbf{q\; }}\; \phi_{\; l,\mathbf{q\; }} \; - \; \sum_\mathbf{q} \; \bar\phi_{l+1,\mathbf{q}} \; \; \;  \phi_{l+1,\mathbf{q}}} \; \; \; \; 
e^{- \sum_\mathbf{q} \; \bar\psi_{\, l,\mathbf{q}} \; \psi_{\, l,\mathbf{q}} \; \; - \;  \sum_\mathbf{q} \; \bar\psi_{\, l+1,\mathbf{q}} \; \; \; \psi_{\, l+1,\mathbf{q}}}
\\
|\phi_l\rangle\otimes|\psi_l\rangle
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
\left[1-\delta H\right]
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
\langle\phi_{l+1}|\otimes\langle\psi_{l+1}|\,.
$$

Here, we put all the integrals together to keep the expression shorter. Now, we look at the bracket term inside:

$$
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
\left[1-\delta H\right]
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle = 
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle-\delta
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
H
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
\\
=\langle\phi_l|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\langle\psi_l|\psi_{l+1}\rangle-\delta
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
H
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
\\
=\langle\phi_l|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\langle\psi_l|\psi_{l+1}\rangle-\delta
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
(H_e + H_p + H_{ep})
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
\\
=\langle\phi_l|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\langle\psi_l|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
-
\delta
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
H_e 
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
-
\delta
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
 H_p 
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
-
\delta
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
 H_{ep}
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
\\
=\langle \phi_l| \phi_{l+1} \rangle \langle \psi_l |\psi_{l+1} \rangle
- \delta \langle \phi_l |\phi_{l+1}\rangle \langle\psi_l|H_e |\psi_{l+1}\rangle
-
\delta
\langle\phi_l|H_p|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\langle\psi_l|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
-
\delta
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
 H_{ep}
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle\,.
$$

The first 3 terms should be familiar from other examples where the types of the operators are not mixed. For the last term, the bosonic operators act on $\phi$ states and the fermionic act on $\psi$. This means that $a$ gets replaced by $\psi$ and $c$ by $\phi$, as usual. After that, we have

$$
\langle \phi_l| \phi_{l+1} \rangle \langle \psi_l |\psi_{l+1} \rangle
- S_e\delta \langle \phi_l |\phi_{l+1}\rangle \langle\psi_l |\psi_{l+1}\rangle
-
S_p\delta
\langle\phi_l|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\langle\psi_l|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
-
S_{ep}\delta
\langle\phi_l|\otimes\langle\psi_l|
|\phi_{l+1}\rangle\otimes|\psi_{l+1}\rangle
\\
= e^{-\delta (S_e + S_p + S_{ep})}\langle \phi_l| \phi_{l+1} \rangle \langle \psi_l |\psi_{l+1} \rangle\,.
$$

The rest follows the usual procedure: reinsert the term into the product and collect all the multiples to form a "time" integral. From there, you can go to the Matsubara form, like the one in the book.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Two followup questions:
i. The Hamiltonian in the problem statement does not have a tensor product, should it be $n_q  \otimes (a_{q, j} + a^\dagger_{-q, j})$ instead to match the tensor product of the basis states?

Comment: ii. In the last expression your response, there are the inner products $\langle \phi_l| \phi_{l+1} \rangle \langle \psi_l |\psi_{l+1} \rangle$, but the desired expression for $S_{el\_ph} \; $ includes no extra exponential terms to account for either inner product. Is the reason that $\langle \phi_l| \phi_{l+1} \rangle$ is included in $S_{el}$, and $ \langle \psi_l |\psi_{l+1} \rangle$, which gives the $- i \omega_n$ term, is included in $S_{ph}$?

Comment: (i) Yup, technically there should be a tensor product. However, it's generally understood that the two operator species act on different Fock spaces and the tensor product symbol is dropped for conciseness. (ii) That's right. See Eq.(4.27) in A&S. You will see that this term is combined with the exponential coming from the coherent resolvent term to give $\partial_\tau$ in the exponential that then is converted into $-i\omega_n$ when you go to the Matsubara formulation